# concatenate function and variable number

Tags: matlab

I've did my code like that :

```
r= randper(3)
    switch num2str(r(i))
    case '1' F1=func1(var1);
    case '2' F2=func2(var2);
    case '3' F3=func3(var3);
    otherwise disp('error');
    end
```

In Matlab, i coudn't find the way to concatenate r with "func" and that could e read as a function not as string

Usually in other langage I could do it like that (it's just an example)

```
  r= randper(3)
    F+r(i)=func+r(i)(var+r(i))
```

Q: How could I shorten my code  in one line ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, there's two ways of doing this: the quick way, and the nice way.

The quick way uses [eval](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/eval.html) which evaluates a string as though it were m-code.

```
r= randper(3)
eval('F' + num2str(r(i)) + ' = func' + r(i) + '(var' + r(i) + ')');
```

The nice way creates an array of function pointers and then calls those:

```
func{1} = @func1;
func{2} = @func2;
func{3} = @func3;

r = randperm(3);

F{r(i)} = func{r(i)}(var(r(i)));
```

The above method helps avoid the myriad of issues that can crop up when you have used eval.

Comment: Tha nice way is perfect ! Thank you !